# Filter a list of folders obtained via ls using a regex expression

Tags: regex, bash

### Context

I have an `ls` command which gives me a list of folder `basename`s, as follows:

```
INPUT:
bash$ ls -d /nfs_archivedbuilds/build/mx/${VERSION_NAME}/${OPERATING_SYSTEM}/* | xargs -n1 basename

OUTPUT: 
4750070-190311-0913-3603182
4761979-190319-SHELVE-3617880
4763232-190319-2049-3618496
4763232-190320-SHELVE-3619115
4764259-190320-1402-3619606
4764259-190320-cifx-6274238
4764339-190320-2049-3620637
4764339-190320-SHELVE-3620115
4764339-190320-cifx-6274274
```

These folders are ordered from the oldest (first result) to the newest (last result).

I have a logic in place which starts by checking the newest: if it's good (I make some checks about the content of the folder) I want to keep it, else I want to analyze the second-newer (and so on).

In order to do this, I start by getting the `tail -1`:

```
SETUPS_CONTROL=1
MY_SETUP=$(ls -d /nfs_archivedbuilds/build/mx/${VERSION_NAME}/${OPERATING_SYSTEM}/* | xargs -n1 basename | tail -${SETUPS_CONTROL})
... doing some stuff to check
```

... and if it ends up not to be good, I increase `SETUPS_CONTROL` and get again `MY_SETUP`, this time with a `+1` tail.

### Question

I would like to keep the same logic, but being able to filter out, already in my `ls` command, every folder which is *not made* of numbers only. 
For example:

- The folder `4750070-190311-0913-3603182` would be good for me, because it's only numbers and dashes
- The folder `4761979-190319-SHELVE-3617880` would not be good for me, because it contains a word (`SHELVE`) and it's not only made of numbers and dashes.

Currently, when I apply my loop to determine whether it's good, I'm forced to do a regex on each result I obtain to determine whether it's good or not:

```
if [[ ${MY_SETUP} =~ "^[0-9-]+$" ]] 
then
    #my setup might be good
else
    #my setup is not good already, no need to further my checks
fi
```

This works fine, but I was wondering if I couldn't filter the list *directly in my `ls` command* instead of getting whatever, and having to loop to understand whether it's good or not.

### My attempt

I have tried to pipe a `grep "my regex expression"` into the command:

```
ls -d /nfs_archivedbuilds/build/mx/${VERSION_NAME}/${OPERATING_SYSTEM}/* | xargs -n1 basename | grep "^[0-9-]+$"
```

... but it returns an empty result. 
Same with single quote:

```
ls -d /nfs_archivedbuilds/build/mx/${VERSION_NAME}/${OPERATING_SYSTEM}/* | xargs -n1 basename | grep '^[0-9-]+$'
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Remove double quotes from the regex pattern, `if [[ ${MY_SETUP} =~ ^[0-9-]+$ ]] `.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew nope, same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `-E` while doing grep with regular expression, please add `grep -E`